# Does UNDROP restore grants to the undropped object?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges

If a table, schema or database is dropped accidentally, and a minute later undropped - will it lose all privileges that were granted on it?

I have read the Snowflake documentation, but they don't seem to mention that.

Comment: Hi - What happened when you tested this?

Comment: Logically it should retain. Because its coming from older version kept as part of time travel. Test and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grants will be recovered along with the table, meaning the roles that had the privilege on the table/object will be available for use

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles#columns
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/undrop

Comment: The links are useless, they say nothing about the grants. But I have tested, and you are right, the grants are intact.